Does Webpack need an entry and output?
I am migrating an old gulp project over to webpack, and wondered if it was possible to make a webpack project that doesn't require the entry and output options, I have a series of tasks that need performing, but I don't actually have the data for an entry and output options.
What I mean is this... this is a typical webpack project
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const isProduction = argv.mode === 'production';

    return {
        mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
        entry: {
            main: './src/index.js', // Adjust for your JS entry
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js',
        },
...

However I don't need entry or output, as my tasks take care of that, how do I get round this problem?
This is the full code
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
require('dotenv').config();

// Register Handlebars helpers
handlebars.registerHelper('concat', (a, b) => a + b);

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const isProduction = argv.mode === 'production';

    return {
        mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
        entry: {
            main: './src/index.js', // Adjust for your JS entry
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js',
        },
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
            },
            port: 7777,
            hot: true,
            open: true,
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    plugins: [
                                        require('autoprefixer')({
                                            overrideBrowserslist: [
                                                'IE >= 11',
                                                'Edge >= 12',
                                                'Firefox >= 50',
                                                'Chrome >= 55',
                                                'Safari >= 8',
                                            ],
                                            grid: true,
                                        }),
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.hbs$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'handlebars-loader',
                            options: {
                                helperDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers'),
                                partialDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/partials'),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|json)$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                    generator: {
                        filename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/index.hbs',
                inject: 'body',
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: './src/data/**/*.json',
                        to: 'data/[name][ext]',
                        transform(content) {
                            const json = JSON.parse(content.toString());
                            if (json.someValue) {
                                delete json.otherValue;
                            }
                            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),
            }),
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimize: isProduction,
            minimizer: [
                new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        format: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                    },
                    extractComments: false,
                }),
            ],
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
            },
        },
    };
};

This is the code I am trying to convert
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars'),
    HandlebarsFilter = require("handlebars"),
    Filter = require("handlebars.filter"),
    layouts = require('handlebars-layouts'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sassLint = require('gulp-sass-lint'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    merge = require('gulp-merge-json');

const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const jsonConcat = require('gulp-json-concat')
const json_refs = require('gulp-json-refs')
const htmlhint = require("gulp-htmlhint")
const Contentstack = require('contentstack')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
require('dotenv').config()

Filter.registerHelper(HandlebarsFilter);

global.fetch = fetch
global.Headers = fetch.Headers

const Stack = new Contentstack.Stack({
    'api_key': process.env.CONTENTSTACK_API_KEY,
    'delivery_token': process.env.CONTENTSTACK_DELIVERY_TOKEN,
    'environment': process.env.CONTENTSTACK_ENVIRONMENT,
    "region": Contentstack.Region.EU
})

// const Stack = new Contentstack.Stack({
//      'api_key': 'blt066259863543a0d2',
//      'delivery_token': 'csda6aeec93af5a25133f03add',
//      'environment': 'candidate',
//      "region": Contentstack.Region.EU
//  })

handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper(layouts(handlebars.Handlebars));
handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function (a, b) {
    return a + b
})
handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifvalue', function (conditional, options) {
    if (options.hash.value === conditional) {
        return options.fn(this)
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this)
    }
})
handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function (arg1, arg2, options) {
    return (arg1 == arg2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});
handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!=':
            return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!==':
            return (v1 !== v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});

gulp.task('JSON:build', () =>
    gulp.src([
        './src/data/*.json',
        './src/data/**/*.json'
    ])
        .pipe(json_refs())
        .pipe(merge({
            fileName: 'data.json',
            edit: (parsedJson, file) => {
                if (parsedJson.someValue) {
                    delete parsedJson.otherValue
                }

                return parsedJson
            },
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/data'))
)

gulp.task('css:lint', () =>
    gulp.src(['node_modules/my-css/src/scss/**/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss', '!node_modules/my-css/src/scss/libs/**'])
        .pipe(sassLint())
        .pipe(sassLint.format())
        .pipe(sassLint.failOnError())
)

gulp.task('css:build', gulp.series(() =>
    gulp.src(['node_modules/my-css/src/scss/**/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss', '!node_modules/my-css/src/scss/libs/**'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({largeFile: true}))
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            includePaths: ['./node_modules', './node_modules/my-css/src/scss']
        }))
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ['IE >= 11', 'Edge >= 12', 'Firefox >= 50', 'Chrome >= 55', 'Safari >= 8'],
            add: true,
            grid: true
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({rebase: false}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
))

gulp.task('js:build-libs', () =>
    gulp.src([
        './src/js/libs/!(jquery.min)*.js'
    ], {
        allowEmpty: true
    })
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
)

gulp.task('js:build-emulation', () =>
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/my-css/build/js/emulation.min.js'
    ])
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(concat('emulation.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
)

gulp.task('js:build-jquery', () =>
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/my-css/build/js/jquery.min.js'
    ])
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(concat('jquery.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
)

gulp.task('js:build-components', () =>
    gulp.src([
        'src/js/helpers/*.js',
        './src/js/components/*.js'
    ])
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(concat('components.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
)

gulp.task('js:concat', gulp.series('js:build-libs', 'js:build-components', () =>
    gulp.src(['node_modules/my-css/build/js/bundle.min.js', './build/js/libs.min.js', './build/js/components.min.js'], {
        allowEmpty: true
    })
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
))

gulp.task('js:build', gulp.series('js:concat', 'js:build-emulation', 'js:build-jquery', () =>
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/my-css/src/js/**/*.js',
        './src/js/**/*.js',
        '!node_modules/my-css/src/js/libs/*.js',
        '!node_modules/my-css/src/js/helpers/*.js',
        '!node_modules/my-css/src/js/emulation/*.js',
        '!node_modules/my-css/src/js/components/*.js'
    ])
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
))

gulp.task('html:validate', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlhint({
            "id-unique": false,
            "doctype-first": false,
            "attr-value-double-quotes": false,
            "title-require": false,
            "attr-lowercase": false,
            "attr-no-duplication": false,
            "spec-char-escape": false,
            "src-not-empty": false
        }))
        .pipe(htmlhint.failOnError())
})

gulp.task('html:build', gulp.series("css:build", 'js:build', 'html:validate', () =>
    gulp.src(['node_modules/my-css/src/*.html', './src/old-templates/*.html', './src/old-templates/price-event/*.html', './src/old-templates/tradepro/*.html',
        './src/old-templates/worktops/*.html', './src/old-templates/kitchens/*.html', './src/old-templates/bathrooms/*.html', './src/old-templates/get-the-look/*.html',
        './src/old-templates/how-to-guides/*.html', './src/old-templates/latest-offers/*.html', './src/old-templates/buying-guides/*.html', './src/old-templates/help-and-advice/*.html'])
        .pipe(handlebars(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/data/data.json')), {
            batch: ['node_modules/my-css/src/layouts', 'node_modules/my-css/src/partials', 'node_modules/my-css/src/components', 'node_modules/my-css/src/elements',
                "./src/layouts", "./src/partials", "./src/components", "./src/elements"]
        }))
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
))

gulp.task('html-template:join', (cb) => {
    gulp.src(['./src/template-data/**/*.json', "!./src/template-data/**/common/**"])
        .pipe(json_refs({
            loaderOptions: {

                prepareRequest: function (req, callback) {
                    req.set('x-api-key', 'abc123')
                    //req.auth('my-username', 'my-password');
                    console.log("URL: " + req.url)
                    console.log(req)

                    callback(undefined, req)
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(jsonConcat('data.json', function (data) {
            return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data));
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templated-data-combined/'))
        .on('end', cb)
})

function addToCategories(categories, categoryName, subCategoryName, title, url) {
    let currentValues = categories[categoryName];
    const entry = {
        "url": url,
        "title": title
    }

    if (subCategoryName) {

        if (typeof currentValues === 'undefined') {
            //no previous entry for this category and we're creating a sub cat (e.g. /kitchen/specialRange/green.  Create a whole new top level
            const parentEntry = {
                "url": "",
                "title": subCategoryName,
                "subCategoryLinks": [entry]
            }

            categories[categoryName] = [parentEntry];
        } else {
            //we've already got an entry for the top level, so lets find the subCategory if it exists
            const matchingIndex = categories[categoryName].findIndex(item => item.title === subCategoryName);

            if (matchingIndex >= 0) {
                const subItem = categories[categoryName][matchingIndex];
                //we might have a previously defined item - check whether there is a subCategoryLinks property
                if (subItem.hasOwnProperty("subCategoryLinks")) {
                    //add to the list
                    subItem.subCategoryLinks.push(entry);
                } else {
                    //create new list
                    subItem.subCategoryLinks = [entry];
                }
            } else {
                //There is no existing entry for this sub category (e.g. /kitchen exists, but not /specialRange- create one
                const parentEntry = {
                    "url": "",
                    "title": subCategoryName,
                    "subCategoryLinks": [entry]
                }
                categories[categoryName].push(parentEntry);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof currentValues === 'undefined') {
            categories[categoryName] = [entry];
        } else {
            //check whether we already have a sub category in place
            const matchingIndex = categories[categoryName].findIndex(item => item.title === title);
            if (matchingIndex >= 0) {
                //we already have an entry for this, so lets just update the URL
                categories[categoryName][matchingIndex].url = url
            } else {
                categories[categoryName].push(entry)
            }
        }
    }
}

gulp.task('html-template:build', gulp.series('html-template:join', 'css:build', 'js:build', () => {
    const templateData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/templated-data-combined/data.json'))

    for (let key in templateData) {
        const pageData = templateData[key]

        gulp.src('./src/templates/' + pageData.config.template)
            .pipe(handlebars(pageData, {
                batch: ['node_modules/my-css/src/layouts', 'node_modules/my-css/src/partials', 'node_modules/my-css/src/components', 'node_modules/my-css/src/elements',
                    "./src/layouts", "./src/partials", "./src/components", "./src/elements"]
            }))
            .on('error', handleError)
            .pipe(rename(pageData.config.prototypeFile))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
            .pipe(rename(pageData.config.hybrisPath + ".html"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    }
    //build homepage listing
    let categories = {}
    for (let key in templateData) {
        const pageConfig = templateData[key].config

        const titleElements = pageConfig.prototypeTitle.split("/")
        if (titleElements.length === 1) {
            //no category
            addToCategories(categories, "Uncategorised", null, titleElements[0], pageConfig.hybrisPath)
        } else if (titleElements.length === 2) {
            //got a category
            addToCategories(categories, titleElements[0], null, titleElements[1], pageConfig.hybrisPath)
        } else if (titleElements.length === 3) {
            addToCategories(categories, titleElements[0], titleElements[1], titleElements[2], pageConfig.hybrisPath)
        } else {
            console.error("Too many sub categories in " + pageConfig.prototypeTitle)
        }
    }
    const model = {"categories": categories};

    return gulp.src('./src/templates/proto_content_listing_page.hbs')
        .pipe(handlebars(model, {
            batch: ['node_modules/my-css/src/layouts', 'node_modules/my-css/src/partials', 'node_modules/my-css/src/components', 'node_modules/my-css/src/elements',
                "./src/layouts", "./src/partials", "./src/components", "./src/elements"]
        }))
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(rename("contentListingPage.html"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())

}))

const processAllRecords = async (contentType, references) => {
    let Query = Stack.ContentType(contentType).Query();
    let findMore = true
    let recordsRetrieved = 0
    while (findMore) {
        const results = await Query
            .includeCount()
            .includeReference(references)
            .skip(recordsRetrieved)
            .toJSON()
            .find();
        console.log(`${contentType} - call to contentshack returned ${results.count} articles`);
        if (results.length) {
            const result = results[0]
            console.log(`${contentType} - call to contentshack returned ${result.count} articles`);
            if (result.length === 0) {
                findMore = false
            } else {
                for (let innerKey in result) {
                    recordsRetrieved = recordsRetrieved + 1
                    console.log('Create Page:',result[innerKey].hybris_content_mapping.html_file_name)
                    console.log('Create Page:',result[innerKey].hybris_content_mapping.hybris_path + '.html')
                    gulp.src('./src/cms/templates/' + result[innerKey].template)
                        .pipe(handlebars(result[innerKey], {
                            batch: ['./src/layouts',
                                'node_modules/my-css/src/layouts',
                                'node_modules/my-css/src/partials',
                                'node_modules/my-css/src/components',
                                'node_modules/my-css/src/elements',
                                './src/cms/components']
                        }))
                        .on('error', handleError)
                        .pipe(rename(result[innerKey].hybris_content_mapping.html_file_name))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
                        .pipe(rename(result[innerKey].hybris_content_mapping.hybris_path + '.html'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
                        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
                }
            }

        } else {
            console.log('no results found')
        }
    }
    console.log(`${contentType} - Retrieved ${recordsRetrieved} articles from ContentShack`)
}

gulp.task('cms:homepage:build', async (done) => {
    await processAllRecords(
        'primary_landing_page',
        ['reference_usp', 'reference_general_banner_top', 'reference_inspiration_banner', 'reference_general_banner_bottom', 'reference_recall_banner']
    );
    done()
}
)

gulp.task('cms:build', gulp.series('cms:homepage:build', () =>
    gulp.src('build/js/temp', {
        read: false,
        allowEmpty: true
    })
));

gulp.task('robots:build', () =>
    gulp.src('node_modules/my-css/src/robots.txt')
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
)

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('JSON:build', 'html:build', 'robots:build', 'html-template:build', 'cms:build', () =>
        gulp.src('build/js/temp', {read: false, allowEmpty: true})
    // .pipe(clean())
))

gulp.task('local:build', gulp.series('html:build', 'robots:build', 'html-template:build', 'cms:build', () =>
    gulp.src('build/js/temp', {read: false, allowEmpty: true})
))

gulp.task('webserver', () =>
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build",
            serveStaticOptions: {
                extensions: ["html"]
            }
        },
        port: 7777,
        ui: {
            port: 7778
        }
    })
)

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('webserver', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.html', './src/**/*.hbs', './src/**/*.json'], ['html:build'])
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', ['css:build'])
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['js:build'])
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['js:build'])
    gulp.watch('./src/template*/**/*.*', ['html-template:build'])
    gulp.watch('./src/cms/**/*.*', ['cms:build'])
    // gulp.watch('./src/data/*.json', ['JSON:build']);
}))

gulp.task('clean', () =>
    gulp.src('build/', {
        read: false,
        allowEmpty: true
    })
        .pipe(clean())
)

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'webserver', 'watch'))

function handleError(err) {
    console.log(err.toString())
    this.emit('end')
    console.error("An error occurred during the build - exiting.....")
    throw Error(err)
}

You can see how I have my work cut out for me. I have tried googling a solution, and also just removing them, but it gives me errors. If someone would like to steer me in the right direction here, any help would be greatly appreciated

Using the modern html-bundler-webpack-plugin your configuration can be much shorter.
The bundler plugin replaces functionality of many plugins and loaders such as:

html-webpack-plugin
mini-css-extract-plugin
terser-webpack-plugin
handlebars-loader
and many others

Using the bundler plugin you don't need the entry webpack option.
The entry is a template not JS file. SCSS and JS source files should be defined directly in the template.
E.g. ./src/index.hbs:
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to favicon source file -->
    <link href="./favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
    <!-- 
    relative path to SCSS source file
    OR import SCSS file in the ./src/index.js to enable HMR for CSS
    -->
    <link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- relative path to image source file -->
    <img src="./picture.png" />
    <!-- relative path to JS source file -->
    <script src="./index.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </body>
</html>

const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const isProduction = argv.mode === 'production';

  return {
    mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      clean: true, // <= do the same as clean-webpack-plugin
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
      },
      port: 7777,
      hot: true,
      open: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                  plugins: [
                    require('autoprefixer')({
                      overrideBrowserslist: ['IE >= 11', 'Edge >= 12', 'Firefox >= 50', 'Chrome >= 55', 'Safari >= 8'],
                      grid: true,
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|json)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
        entry: {
          // define pages here
          index: 'src/index.hbs', // save generated HTML into build/index.html
        },
        js: {
          filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js', // JS output filename
        },
        css: {
          filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css', // CSS output filename
          hot: true, // enable hot update CSS in browser without a full reload
        },
        preprocessor: 'handlebars', // use handlebars compiler for *.hbs templates
        preprocessorOptions: {
          // an array of relative or absolute paths to helpers, define helpers manually as an object
          // TODO: add your custom helper as separate file into the helpers directory
          // 'concat', (a, b) => a + b)
          helpers: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers')],
          // an array of relative or absolute paths to partials
          partials: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/partials')],
        },
      }),

      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: './src/data/**/*.json',
            to: 'data/[name][ext]',
            transform(content) {
              const json = JSON.parse(content.toString());
              if (json.someValue) {
                delete json.otherValue;
              }
              return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),
      }),
    ],
    optimization: {
      // sass-loader self minimize CSS in production mode
      // html-bundler-webpack-plugin avoid extraction of comments
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          scripts: {
            test: /\.(js|ts)$/, // <= IMPORTANT: split only script files
            chunks: 'all', // <= define this option only under the cache group
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

The output option is required to define a custom output directory output.path, defaults is ./dist.
Instead of clean-webpack-plugin you can define the output.clean: true option.
P.S.
Create a repo on GitHub and I can help you configure your project.

Hi, Thanks for this, is a great starting point... I think my issue is that my project doesn't have an index.js, index.html or index.hbs file... I need to understand how to get round that or how to migrate something across to the index.* file :/

what files are in your project?
The source files can have any name different from index.*.
Can you please show the file tree of your project? Or better create a small repo on GitHub with your files.
